# consumming a web service function soap

Tags: php, soap

i need your help, it's the first time that i use the web services. i have a function named "valeur" when i call this function without parameters it work fine but when i add $min and $ max it doesn't work and it doesn't returned a random value but returned "array".
the service function

> 

```
<?php
include('lib/nusoap.php');

$serveur = new soap_server;
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA =file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
$serveur->register('valeur');
function valeur($min,$max)
  {
  return rand($min,$max);
  }

$serveur->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

and here the client

```
    include('lib/nusoap.php');
$min=$_POST['min'];
$max=$_POST['max'];
$client = new soapclient('http://localhost/projet2/service.php');
$valeur=$client->call("valeur($min,$max)");
$sql="INSERT INTO capteur (latitude, longitude, cp, adr,type,valeur,min,max)
VALUES
('$_POST[lati]','$_POST[longi]','$_POST[cp]','$_POST[adr]','$_POST[type]','$valeur','$_POST[min]','$_POST[max]')";
enter code here
```

Comment: You are treating `"valeur($min,$max)"` as one string, not a function and its arguments, so it's probably being interpreted as an odd (non-existent) function name. Depending exactly how the service is set up, what you might want is `$valeur = $client->valeur($min,$max);`, or if not, try `$valeur = $client->call('valeur', $min, $max);`

Comment: thank you for your reply i tried 
$valeur = $client->valeur($min,$max);
i had this result Call to undefined method soapclient::valeur()
and with
$valeur = $client->call('valeur()', $min, $max);
it's the same result

Comment: i found the solution i have just to convert the value to int (intval()) and make the parameters into an array.